# Topology of blow up of a cone

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, projective-space, morse-theory, blowup

Let $X$ be a real algebraic surface with a unique $A_1$ point at $p \in X$ (that is, the germ of $X$ at $p$ is isomorphic to the germ of $\{x^2+y^2=z^2\}$ at the origin). Let $Y \to X$ be the blow up of $X$ at $p$. Is it true that $X$ is homotopy equivalent to the connected sum of $X$ with $\mathbb{RP}^2$?

We know that the blow up of an affine cone is a copy of $\mathbb{RP}^2$ (see answer in [Blow-up of the affine cone](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2081022/blow-up-of-the-affine-cone)), but how does the gluing work?

Comment: I'm a little confused about the real algebraic geometry stuff, but in the connected sum, you would remove a disk from the projective plane, so topologically, there's not necessarily a closed copy of the projective plane inside of what you have left, right?

Comment: @hunter Yes, but in connected sum you are gluing them along the boundary afterwards.

Comment: If $A$ and $B$ are manifolds, it is not obvious to me that $A \sharp B$ has a closed submanifold isomorphic to $A$. On the other hand, $Y$ always has a submanifold isomorphic to $\mathbb{RP}^2$.

Comment: That is true in general. Look at the orientable surface of genus $g>1$ produced by gluing $g$ tori.